# Integral representation of the Dirac Delta function

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Someone told me, without so much details, that I can use the following representation of $\delta$
$$
\delta(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{g(-i\partial_x)}\tilde{g}(x),
$$
for a suitable function $g$ and where $\tilde{g}(x)=1/\sqrt{2\pi}\int g(y)e^{ixy}dy$ is the Fourier transform of $g$. How to show this? I believe one can start from the $\delta$ definition
\begin{align}
\delta(x)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{ixy}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \frac{1}{g(y)}g(y)e^{ixy}dy\\
\end{align}
and an integration by parts, but what boundary conditions or what properties the function $g$ must have (clearly a series decomposition)?

Comment: No idea what $\frac{1}{g(-i\partial_x)}$ means. $\delta$ is not a function. And $\delta=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ -convergence only in the sense of distributions- where $f_n(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-n}^n e^{ixy}dy$

Answer (score 3):

We start from
$$
\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix\xi} \, d\xi
.
$$

If $g$ is analytic then
$$
g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k
$$
and we define
$$
g(-i\partial_x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(-i\partial_x)^k
.
$$

Note now that
$$
g(-i\partial_x) e^{ix\xi}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(-i\partial_x)^k e^{ix\xi}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(-i\cdot i\xi)^k e^{ix\xi}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\xi^k e^{ix\xi}
= g(\xi) e^{ix\xi}
.
$$

Therefore, applying $g(-i\partial_x)$ on $\delta$ gives
$$
g(-i\partial_x) \delta(x)
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(-i\partial_x) e^{ix\xi} \, d\xi
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(\xi) e^{ix\xi} \, d\xi
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \tilde{g}(x)
$$
from which we conclude
$$
\delta(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} g(-i\partial_x)^{-1} \tilde{g}(x)
.
$$

Comment: What is $g(-i\partial_x) \delta(x)$, you can't consider $\sum_k c_k \delta^{(k)}$ without introducing a new test function space

Comment: @md2perpe  If $g$ is analytic and equal to $e^x$..

Comment: @yngabl. Fixed.

Comment: @reuns. I know that this isn't completely valid, but do you know a better "derivation" of the questionable formula in the question?